# Tengo un error al construir mi pagina en next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

tengo un problema a la hora de construir mi página de next, son páginas estáticas, son algunos admins y logins.

El problema es que al correr `npm run start` luego de la construcción, la página aparece completamente en blanco, sin ningún error en consola ni nada, adjunto imagen de consola luego de esta ejecución.

[image: Imagen de la consola luego de buildear el sistema]

Esta es la imagen del `npm run start` en el navegador.

[image: Npm run start nav]
No tengo idea que puede ser, además cuando entro a una ruta dinámica, es decir, las que tienen [id] o [uid], me redirige al login y me aparece todo, pero al recargar vuelvo a tener el mismo problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien sabe o podría ayudarme a solucionarlo lo agradecería mucho,
Muchas gracias por leer.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que usar `npm run dev` en vez de `npm run start`.

Comment: Hola franxo, gracias por tu respuesta. ¿Cuál sería la diferencia entre usar `npm run dev` y `npm run start`? ¿Por qué usnado `npm run dev` se resolverá el problema?

Comment: Te damos la bienvenida a Stackoverflow en Español. Por favor, completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento general (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla).

Comment: Hola franxo, gracias por la respuesta. Finalmente, tuve que pasar mi app de next.js a React puro. La app la quería poner en producción, con `npm run dev` no tuve ningún problema, era solo a la hora de buildear. Muchas gracias por la respuesta de todas maneras.